# Caching Issue "unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 24 bytes"

Tags: cache

I have never gotten this before when using Craft cms this is the first.

When trying to load my site (locally), I am getting this message

**unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 24 bytes**

I have attached some screenshots of what I am getting in more detail

What am I suppose to do to fix this?

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Weird... try clearing out `craft/storage/runtime/cache` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you that worked. But do you have any idea why that happened?

Comment: No idea... added an answer.  Maybe just keep an eye out to see if it's a recurring issue or a one-time problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like something just got corrupted when saving to `craft/storage/runtime/cache` and now PHP/Craft is having a problem reading the corrupted data from cache.

No idea how it happened, but clearing `craft/storage/runtime/cache` should resolve the issue for now.

Comment: Happened to me when my machine crashed (BSOD)